# Add any SDK to Laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sdk

I'm trying to add [this](http://developers.payulatam.com/en/sdk/) SDK in my Laravel 5.4 application. I downloaded and installed it in `app/resources/assets` and guessing that I can use it in controllers as:

```
require_once '[ruta/payu-php-sdk]/lib/PayU.php';
```

The SDK have some Eviromental variables and Keys.

What do you think is the better approach for this type of SDK in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [Omnipay](https://omnipay.thephpleague.com/), it's a well supported library the has integrations for many different gateways, including [PayU](https://github.com/saitima/omnipay-payu). This library is framework agnostic, so you won't need to change your code should you need to change payment gateways.

You can use `composer` to add these libraries:

```
"require": {
    "omnipay/omnipay": "~2.0",
    "omnipay/payu": "~2.0"
}
```

This way you don't have to keep track of `require`s.

Edit: To add any type of library that doesn't use `composer` already, You could manually tell `composer` to autoload file(s).

For your case, there should be a section in your `composer.json` called `autoload`, here's what you could add:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "ruta/payu-php-sdk/lib/PayU.php"
    ]
},
...
```

This should make the SDK available throughout the application.

Comment: Great advise. But i'm looking for some steps to add any type of library or SDK to laravel 5

Comment: @LuigiLopez I've updated my answer to answer your question better.